# selenium : how to know if a qooxdoo button is enable or not

Tags: qooxdoo

We are using qooxdoo 5.0.2 and selenium for our functional tests.
We try to find a way in selenium to know (html/style/xpath/...) if a QX button is enable/disable.
When We inspect both QX buttons (enable & disable), it seems there is no difference.
Any way to distinguish that, please ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I am curious to know that as well. Apparently, there is no 'disabled' attribute, special CSS class or whatsoever. HTML wise the difference is only in the `opacity: 0.3` applied to the image inside a button `div`. What's the best way to capture by Selenium WebDriver  whether a button is disabled in Qooxdoo JS framework?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, information on the "enabled" state of the buttons is only kept by the qooxdoo object in the execution context, not on the level of the DOM. Can Selenium access the execution context, like more modern Tools like Puppeteer or Playwright? Alternatively, would you could consider monkey-patching `qx.ui.core.Widget._applyEnabled()` in order to set a custom attribute (such as `data-qx-enabled="false"`) on `this.getContentElement().getDomElement()`. If you think a more general solution is necessary, we are happy to review a PR that would integrate it in v6.

Comment: Nothing at DOM level ? this is what I was afraid =;o/

I'll check how to do your tricky solution ... thanks. (have that in the new version v6, would be great yes^^)